# Package manager encoding error

Tags: package, character-encoding

Upon running `package-list-packages`, I get the following error.

```
These default coding systems were tried to encode text
in the buffer ` *temp*':
  (iso-latin-1-dos (3242 . 37326) (3243 . 40165))
However, each of them encountered characters it couldn't encode:
  iso-latin-1-dos cannot encode these: 野 鳥
```

How can I set the default package manager encoding to be `utf-8`?

Comment: Does `(set-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)` help?

Comment: In reality though, something should be done about this server-side.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your preference, you can use the following line in your `.emacs` to set your default coding system to utf-8. That resolved the problem for me, and I haven't noticed any other negative side effects yet.

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

Comment: Just make sure you place the form *before* something like `(require 'package)`

Answer (score 1):

If you need a default encoding different from utf-8, you could use an advice around the list-package function to force use of utf-8 encoding :
ex:

```
(defun pte/list-packages (org-fun &rest args)
  "Ensure to set `buffer-file-coding-system' to utf-8 before calling `list-packages'."
  (let ((buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8))
    (apply org-fun args)))

(advice-add 'list-packages :around #'pte/list-packages)
```

In my daily use I need to use :

```
(prefer-coding-system 'windows-1252)
```

So I've advised the list-package function ... hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a line like this in your init file?

```
(set-language-environment "Latin-1")
```

If so, try removing it.